Should I install both protection upgrades and protection units in an exosuit?
I have two types of technology upgrades available for my exosuit: items listed as protection units, and items listed as protection upgrades. The ones listed as upgrades have text that generally says something like "an almost total rework of the  Protection, this upgrade brings unparalleled improvements to  Shielding and  Protection", whereas the upgrade units give a percentage of resistance.
Should I install both, or do I just need to install one or the other? For example:

I have a "High-Energy Bio-Integrity Unit" which is a protection upgrade, and I can build a "Radiation Reflector" which is a protection unit. Should I install both?
I have a "Specialist De-Toxifier" and I can build a "Toxin Suppressor". Should I install both?
I have a "Carbon Sublimation Pump" and I can build a "Coolant Network". Should I install both?
I have a "Nitroged-Based Thermal Stabilizer" and I can build a "Thermic Layer". Should I install both?

And then for something similar but a little different:

I have a "Deep Water Depth Protection" which says it is an "almost total rework of the Aeration Membrance", and I can also build an Aeration Membrane. Will crafting and installing an Aeration Membrane bring any extra benefits?


Is this from Worlds part 1 update?

@pinckerman No, these upgrades have been around for a while.

Short answer: yes.
Hazard Protection Upgrades offer an extra layer of shield against specific hazards, in addition to those offered by the Exosuit's built-in hazard protection. Up to three protections upgrades can be installed in the technology section of the Exosuit.
Their advantage is they drain at the same fixed rate regardless of the strength of the hazard. Their downside is they do not recharge themselves.
Hazard Protection Units are technologies that provide 21% extra hazard resistance.
So yes, it's better to have them both if you often find extreme planets. Protection Units give a passive bonus and don't need to be recharged, they are very useful.
More info on No Man's Sky wiki.
